# How to round numbers in elements and return the rounded results in a sql query

Tags: sqlite

Let's say there is a table A with 2 rows, index and value.

The value can be any float number.

If the value is < 0, then it should be rounded to 0.
If the value is > 0, then it should be rounded to 1.

Give a sql query that returns the rounded version of value.

For example,

```
index | value
0       0.356
1       -1.45
2       2.36
```

should turn into

```
index | value
0        1
1        0
2        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `case` to return `0` or `1` from the column `value`:

```
select 
  index,
  case 
    when value <= 0 then 0 
    else 1
  end value 
from A
```

If there is a case of null values:

```
select 
  index,
  case
    when value <= 0 then 0 
    when value > 0 then 1
  end value 
from A
```